# Why does "foo = foo || {};" not work?

Tags: javascript

I was experimenting around with some javascript in my browser console and and not sure exactly why this doesn't work. The following code in the console and jsfiddle on my attempts throws the error: *Uncaught ReferenceError: foo is not defined*

```
foo = foo || {};
```

The way i interpret this is: if foo of the global object (window in this case) doesn't exist, then create it as an empty object.

Alternatively, the code `window.foo = window.foo || {}`; works as I would expect. Assigning a value beforehand to foo with `foo = 'bar'` makes the original statement work when running afterwards as well.

Comment: `var foo = foo || {};` This will work as expected, atleast in Chrome.

Comment: correct, it works when using the var keyword, but not without.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to check whether `foo` is defined first:

```
foo = typeof foo !== 'undefined' ? foo : {};
```

It may be a little unintuitive, but there is a difference between being undefined and having a value of `undefined` (which `window.foo` returns when `window` doesn't have a `foo` property).

A better way would be to add the `var` keyword:

```
var foo = foo || {};
```

Which works because JavaScript hoists the variable declaration up to the top of the current scope, declaring `foo` and giving it a value of `undefined`:

```
var foo;

foo = foo || {};
```

Comment: ah yes that clears it up. thank you for your detailed answer, much appreciated!